# How to cut the power on power pin 1 programmatically?

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+

Is there a way to cut the power on power pin 1 on Raspberry Pi 3B+, using a command or force this on reboot?

Comment: Hello! Since the Pi3 and the Pi3B+ are actually equipped with a different power management IC it would be nice to clarify which model you're referring to. Tags and question body differ. Thanks.

Comment: @Ghanima The board is Pi3B+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to control any of the voltage rail pins (the 3V3 pins, the 5V pins, and the ground pins).

They are hard wired to the input power line.

The schematics are available at [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md).